# ACCESO A BASE DE DATOS MYSQL- ERROR ACCESO DENEGADO AL USUARIO 'XXX'@'localhost'

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, vps

Hola a todos buenas tardes, estoy trabajando en un proyecto para mi sitio web y me está volviendo loco.
Tengo un LAMP server con Ubuntu 18.04.1, PHP 7.3 y MySQL.
En este servidor he creado una base de datos llamada bosstrader y en ella una tabla llamada usuarios.
Desde mi sitio web busco que las personas se registren en mi sitio y sus datos queden guardados en la base de datos bosstrader tabla usuarios.
La cosa es que cada vez que intento acceder a la conexión usando PHP me da el error "Error connection: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)".

> "Error connection: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user
> 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"
>
> A continuación detallo todo lo que he realizado y que no me ha funcionado:

> PREPARACIÓN:

1. Editar el archivo mysql.cnf --> nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
   editar la línea "bind-address = 127.0.0.1" a "bind-address = 0.0.0.0 ", y hasta he intentado comentándola "#bind-address = 127.0.0.1"
2. reiniciar el servidor --> sudo service mysql restart

> CREACIÓN DE USUARIO Y ASIGNACION DE PERMISOS

1. Crear usuario  'admin'@'localhost' con su pasword --> CREATE USER 'admin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'strongpass';
2. Darle todos los permisos --> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON bosstrader TO 'admin'@'localhost';
   2.1 Asegurar permisos de insersión y modificación -->GRANT CREATE, SELECT,UPDDATE, INSERT, DELETE ON * . * TO 'admin'@'localhost';
3. Actualizar memoria de permisos --> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
4. Me he asegurado que el usuario admin si se encuentre -->SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user;
   [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUfHw.png]
5. He revisado que tenga los permisos --> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'admin'@'localhost';
   [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9hEW.png]
6. Pero al tratar de ver que usuarios tienen acceso a x bases de datos, no me aparece el usuario creado al que le he dado los permisos --> select user,host,insert_priv,update_priv,delete_priv from mysql.db where db='bosstrader'; //obtengo empity set!

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3TY6.png]

Por otro lado, la conexión en entorno de desarrollo local, me funciona de maravilla, pero por si las dudas dejo mi PHP:

```
  <?php

class DB{
  private $host;
  private $db;
  private $user;
  private $password;
  private $charset;

  public function __construct(){
      $this->host     = 'localhost';
      $this->db       = 'bosstrader';
      $this->user     = 'admin';
      $this->password = "stronpassword";
      $this->charset  = 'utf8mb4';
  }

  function connect(){
  
      try{
          
          $connection = "mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db . ";charset=" . $this->charset;
          $options = [
              PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
              PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
          ];
          $pdo = new PDO($connection, $this->user, $this->password, $options);
  
          return $pdo;

      }catch(PDOException $e){
          print_r('Error connection: ' . $e->getMessage());
      }   
  }
}






?>
```

> ANOTACIÓN IMPORTANTE
> Todo lo anterior lo he intentado con usuarios de permisos '%'.

1. Crear usuario  'admin'@'%' con su password --> CREATE USER 'admin'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'strongpass';
   y he realizado todos los pasos de asignarle permisos.

Si alguien sabe como puedo lograr solucionar esto, les agradecería mucho.

Comment: En tu explicación hay confusión sobre el entorno exacto donde el problema ocurre. ¿Es un servidor tuyo propio, es un servidor remoto de hosting compartido o algo así? ¿Has probado a conectarte por consola con ese usuario/password? Me parece que la forma en que explicas el problema es confusa. Ayudaría que de entrada expongas el problema describiendo bien el contexto, así será más fácil analizar luego toda la información que pones. He intentando entender lo que pasa, haciendo un esfuerzo, pero me pierdo entre tantas explicaciones de cosas que haces y no haces.

Comment: Es importante que indiques la versión de MySQL que estas usando

Comment: Asignaste al usuario permisos globales, no a una base de datos específica; es lógico que no aparezca en la consulta #6 de usuarios que tienen acceso a `bosstrader`. El error puede deberse a un error al teclear la contraseña y, aunque supongo que algo editaste para publicar la pregunta, no está de más que verifiques, porque cuando creas el usuario asignas la contraseña como `strongpass`, pero en el script usas `stronpassword`.